# Can`t connect to WCF service from outside of my local network

Tags: c#, wcf

I am learning to write WCF services and I wrote my simple service going step by step with example from book I am reading. Service works fine on my PC and every device connected to my LOCAL network. When I try to connect from "outside" of my local network if fails to see service (both via client app I wrote and via browser(MEX)).
My host app.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>

      <services>
       <service name="WCF_1_MagicEightBallService.MagicEightBallService"
                behaviorConfiguration="MagicEightBallServiceMEXBehavior">

         <endpoint address=""
                   binding="basicHttpBinding"
                   contract="WCF_1_MagicEightBallService.IMagicEightBall">
         </endpoint>

         <endpoint address="mex"
                   binding="mexHttpBinding"
                   contract="IMetadataExchange">
         </endpoint>

         <host>
           <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://[my ip]:8080/MagicEightBallService"/>
           </baseAddresses>
         </host>

       </service>
      </services>

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MagicEightBallServiceMEXBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

My ip is my external ip, but I have tried using ip with and without using wifi router and with different ports.

Comment: Unless you have a commercial internet plan, your ISP more than likely will block most default web ports (25, 80, 8080, 443, etc.).

Comment: @Cameron so there is no way to host web service by myself? Can hosting with IIS help?

Comment: You can host it inside IIS, you'll just need to use a non-default port. Just pick a number between like ... 10000 and 65535.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as mentioned Cameron in the comments, problem was with ISP blocking my ports. This answer might be a little bit off topic, but for everyone with similar problem, here what I did:

1. scanned open ports with free console-based utility "nmap" with command:
    nmap target.hostname.com
2. then I rechecked all ports with "unknown" service with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ (you, of course, can use any other website). They were all open and with Windows command:
   netstat -aon |find /i "listening" |find "port"
    I got PIDs of apps that were using them.
3. I chose port used by app that I don`t need running, closed it and used that port for IIS server binding of website hosting my WCF service.

It worked and I could get remote access via my external IP address.